# Constructing the FROM in SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, variables

I'm looking to pull a specific line from a number of table that have a field name criteria1. The problem I'm having is that when I combine the Owner and Table Name and try to call "select criteria1 from @t where linenum = 1" SQL is expecting @t to be a table. I need to know how to construct the full table name and then pass it to this query. I know I can us a programming language to access the DB but i need this to be in SQL. If someone knows of a better way of doing this that would be great too.

```
declare @next as varchar
declare @owner varchar

while 1=1
begin
  set @next = (select top 1 o.name FROM syscolumns c inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id 
               where c.name = 'criteria1' and o.id > @next order by o.id)    

  if @next is null
    break
  else
  begin
    set @owner = (select top 1 u.name 
                  FROM syscolumns c inner join 
                       sysobjects o on c.id = o.id left join 
                       sysusers u on o.uid=u.uid
                  where c.name = 'criteria1' and o.id = @next order by o.id)
    declare @t as varchar
    set @t = @owner+'.'+@next
    select criteria1 from @t where linenum = 1      
  end
  continue
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the entire query you want as a varchar() and then execute it with the `sp_executesql` stored procedure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

In your case, that bit at the end becomes

```
declare @sql varchar(512);
set @sql = 'select criteria1 from ' + @t + ' where linenum = 1'          
sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: As a side note, you need to very careful about any possible injection when going this route.

Comment: @Chris +1 - but if MisterBigs is pulling the tablenames from sysobjects he should be okay. Unless someone has created a table called 'dual;drop table students;--' http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Use QUOTENAME(@T) when building the string.

Comment: Thanks banjollity, this sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the following construct in a stored procedure?

```
  CASE @tablename
     WHEN 'table1' THEN SELECT * FROM table1
     WHEN 'table2' THEN SELECT * FROM table2
     WHEN 'table3' THEN SELECT * FROM table3
     WHEN 'table4' THEN SELECT * FROM table4
  END
```

In case you're married to dynamic SQL (considered to be a bad choice for this problem space), [this guide to dynamic SQL should help a lot](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table). It helped me and I've used dynamic SQL extensively.

Comment: Thanks I'll check out the link you posted. I don't know the names of the tables and there are a few thousands of them so a sp would not be good for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. This is what I ended up with.

```
declare cur cursor for
select   u.name + '.' + o.name tname
    FROM sysobject o left join 
         syscolumns c  on c.id = o.id left join 
         sysusers u on o.uid=u.uid
    where c.name = 'criteria1'

declare @tn as varchar(512)
open cur
fetch next from cur into @tn

create table holding_table ( val varchar(512), table_name varchar(512))
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'insert into holding_table select criteria1, ''' + @tn + ''' from ' + @tn + ' where linenum = 1'
    execute sp_executesql @sql  
    fetch next from cur into @tn    
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a view can be used here?

```
CREATE VIEW vCriterias
AS
SELECT 'Table1' AS TableName,
linenum,
criteria1
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table2' AS TableName,
linenum,
criteria1
FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table3' AS TableName,
linenum,
criteria1
FROM Table3

go
```

Then selection is like:

```
   SELECT criteria1
   FROM vCriterias
   WHERE linenum = 3 
   AND TableName IN ('Table1','Table3')
```